# What kind of comprehension is this?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

One of my students found that, for `ell` (a list of string) and `estr` (a string), the following expression is `True` iff a member of `ell` is contained in `estr`:

```
any(t in estr for t in ell)
```

Can anyone explain why this is syntactically legal, and if so what does the comprehension generate?

Comment: `(t in estr for t in ell)` is a generator expression, you could think about it as a "generator comprehension" although that isn't the term that is used

Answer (score 2):

This is a generator expression.

```
func_that_takes_any_iterable(i for i in iterable)
```

It's like a list comprehension, but a generator, meaning it only produces one element at a time:

```
>>> a = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> b = (i for i in range(10))
>>> print(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print(b)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fb9113fae40>
>>> print(list(b))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print(list(b))
[]
```

When using a generator expression in isolation, the parentheses are required for syntax reasons. When creating one as an argument to a function, the syntax allows for the extra parentheses to be absent.

Most functions don't care *what* type of iterable they're given - list, tuple, dict, generator, etc - and generators are perfectly valid. They're also marginally more memory-efficient than list comprehensions, since they don't generate the entire thing up front. For `all()` and `any()`, this is especially good, since those methods short-circuit as soon as they would return `False` and `True` respectively.

---

As of python 3.8, the syntactic restrictions for the walrus operator `:=` are similar - in isolation, it must be used inside its own set of parentheses, but inside another expression it can generally be used without them.

Comment: Most excellent explanation - very clear and complete. And in many contexts, much better than a list comprehension that will later be iterated over.

Comment: *"They're also **marginally more memory-efficient** than list comprehensions, since they don't generate the entire thing up front. For all() and any(), this is **especially good**, since those methods short-circuit as soon as they would return False and True respectively."* By "especially good", I assume you mean "considerably more time-efficient" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is syntactically legal because *it's not a list*. Anything of the form (x for x in array) is a generator. Think of it like *lazy list*, which will generate answer only when you ask.

Now generator are also an iterable so it's perfectly fine for it to be inside an any() function.

```
willBeTrue = any(True for i in range(20))
```

So this will basically generate 20 Trues and any function looks for any true value; thus will return True.

Now coming to your expression:

```
ans = any(t in estr for t in ell)
```

This {t in estr} returns a boolean value. Now generator makes len(ell) amount of those boolean value and any thinks good.. since atleast one is true I return True.

Comment: `willBeTrue = any(True for i in range(20))` will only generate **one** `True` - aftrer that the `any` is statisfied and no more Trues will be generated.